# Communication failing on one specific server

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

After a time online one of my servers rejects to communicate with exactly one other server in the network.

There is only the default route

```
admin@server:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Communication with all other servers is fine

```
admin@server:~$ traceroute 172.50.1.148 
traceroute to 172.50.1.148 (172.50.1.148), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.10.254 (192.168.10.254)  1.874 ms  1.801 ms  1.742 ms
 2  172.50.1.148 (172.50.1.148)  269.883 ms  273.890 ms  278.833 ms
```

just one of them seems not available

```
admin@server:~$ traceroute 172.50.1.149
traceroute to 172.50.1.149 (172.50.1.149), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
```

but all other systems in the network can access this server. Bringing the interface down and up again resolves the issue, which is not a solution.

The Server is a virtual machine running on ESXI 6

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 00:0c:29:97:5f:1e
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master rom ethernet physical logical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=pcnet32 driverversion=1.35 ip=192.168.10.11 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=255 mingnt=6 multicast=yes
   resources: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=128) memory:ebb00000-ebb0ffff
```

Comment: Can we have more information like NIC model?